# Ruby Vs Python - Socket Libraries

Tags: python, ruby, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a concept I'd like to work on that requires the use of low-level sockets (i.e.: no frameworks or wrappers, just the standard send/recv pattern included in most standard libraries.

I'm familiar with both Ruby and Python, and from my (limited) experience they seem to have similar socket libraries. What I'd like to know is if either language has any advantage, whether it be with performance, stability, ease-of-use or otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to any number of existing Python vs. Ruby discussions already on SO

Comment: It would help if you write more about the application you're about to build. In general, I don't think it matters much which language you'll pick, Ruby and Python are pretty similar in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

What a language you know better, that'll fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Both language offer a very thin wrapper above the underlying OS socket library. You won't get much difference.